# Why does the nil-coalescing operator return an optional?

Tags: swift, option-type

I use *Swift*'s nil-coalescing operator in a chain to print one of three values. The first two are optional, the last one is non-optional:

```
let optionalString: String? = nil
let optionalError: Error? = MyError.anError
let defaultString: String = "default"
print(optionalString ?? (optionalError ?? defaultString))
```

I was surprised to see that this code prints

> `Optional(MyError.anError)`

to the console. I was expecting a non-optional:

> `MyError.anError`

#### Why is this an optional?

*The error is defined as follows:*

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case anError
}
```

---

I know that there are two implementations of the nil-coalescing operator:

1. `func ?? <T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () throws -> T) rethrows -> T`

and

2. `func ?? <T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () throws -> T?) rethrows -> T?`

According to this, `??` should return an optional (`T?`) **only if the `defaultValue` is an optional as well (`T?`)**. But this is not the case:

The default value for the first `??` operator is `(optionalError ?? defaultString)`. To evaluate this value's type, we need to evaluate the result of the second `??` operator. As `defaultString` is of type `String` and thus a non-optional, function (1) is used for the nil-coalescing operator. Hence, the result of `(optionalError ?? defaultString)` must be non-optional as well, which is the default value for the first `??` operator. So again, function (1) is used for the nil-coalescing operator and thus, `optionalString ?? (optionalError ?? defaultString)` *should* return a *non-*optional.

Apparently, there is a flaw in my logic, but I don't see it. Any explanation for this?

Comment: imagine that your `T` is `Error?`, and it immediately makes perfect sense why you get optional when printing your error.

Comment: There must be something missing, `optionalError ?? defaultString` does not compile. – Perhaps you have defined `extension String: Error { }` ? But then your code just prints "anError" in my test.

Comment: Agreed. The code you posted here either doesn't compile, or if helped to compile works exactly as you suggest it should. Can you post a full example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @MartinR: There is nothing missing ...

Comment: ... @RobNapier: For me, the code does compile in a playground with Xcode 11.2. However, your comments pushed me in the right direction to understand the problem better. I hope... ;) → See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59294698/2062785) below.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer:* I wasn't sure if I should add this as a supplement to my question or if I should post it as an answer. I decided for the latter. It's not a bullet-proof explanation, but I think it's "close enough" for many who might run into the same problem.

---

#### What's going wrong: The Big Picture

The two comments stating that the code provided doesn't compile for the commentators pushed me in the right direction:

I copied the code in a blank playground and ran it. For me, it *did* compile, but it also showed a warning which it didn't show before *(because for some reason, Auto completion and compiler warnings were broken in the original project)*.

[image: Playground screenshot]

The warning

> Expression implicitly coerced from 'Any?' to 'Any'

tells me that the expression `(optionalError ?? defaultString)` is apparently evaluated as type `Any?`, which is an optional. The compiler then chooses the `??` operator function (1) to evaluate the entire expression which requires that its default value `(optionalError ?? defaultString)` is non-optional. Thus, this value is implicitly coerced from `Any?` to `Any`. And that's why `Optional(MyError.anError)` is printed.

---

#### Why is this going wrong?

There are two questions remaining:

1. Why does the compiler choose operator function (1)?
2. Why is `(optionalError ?? defaultString)` evaluated to `Any?`?

I don't have an answer for **question 1**,

but my guess would be that the compiler simply assigns a higher precedence to function (1) when the parameter types don't match and it's unclear which function to use. (I'll be happy to be corrected.)

Regarding **question 2**:

`optionalError` is of type `MyError?` and `defaultString` is of type `String`. The signature of the `??` operator functions read:

1. `func ?? <T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () throws -> T) rethrows -> T`
2. `func ?? <T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () throws -> T?) rethrows -> T?`

So both parameters, `optional` and `defaultValue` must have the "same" generic type (only that in the first case, one parameter is an optional of that particular type and the other one is not). `MyError` and `String` are obviously *not* the same type. So in order for this to match the criteria of the function signature, the compiler must coerce both types to `Any`.

So `MyError?` is coerced to `Any?` and apparently, `String` is also coerced to `Any?` and thus, function (2) is used which evaluates (optionalError ?? defaultString)`to`Any?`.

That again raises the question why function (2) is used in this case which kind of contradicts my assumption for question (1), but **my main take-away here is that it's simply a bad idea to use two different types with the nil-coalescing operator**.

---

#### Background:

*I got this code example from a textbook on RxSwift which is slightly different as it uses a generic type that is required to conform to `CustomStringConvertible`:*

```
func print<T: CustomStringConvertible>(label: String, event: Event<T>) {
    print(label, event.element ?? event.error ?? event)
}
```

*What got me experimenting with this in the first place was that when I ran the code from the book it printed an optional whereas the book claimed that it would print a non-optional.*